# Do I need a comma?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

Note that I'm supposed to use Oxford comma. Now do I need a comma at the place of the question mark?

> When such change adversely affects the system, vulnerability increases[?]
>   and a banking crisis becomes more likely.

Comment: Oxford comma only applies to lists of three items or more. You only have two.

Comment: You're right. Not sure how I got confused.

Comment: Who 'supposes' (requires) you to use the Oxford comma? Even the OUP are having second thoughts about a broad-brush approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma isn't needed in this case. Don't get confused with "When such change adversely affects the system" being the first item in the list. Since there are only two items, no comma is needed.